# Using Complex datatype with python SUDS client

Tags: python, web-services, suds

I am trying to call webservice from python client using SUDS. When I call a function with a complex data type as input parameter, it is not passed correctly, but complex data type is getting returned correctly froma webservice call.

```
Webservice Type:
    Soap Binding 1.1
    Document/Literal 
Webserver: 
    Weblogic 10.3 
Python Version: 2.6.5, SUDS version: 0.3.9
```

here is the code I am using:

Python Client:

```
from suds.client import Client
url = 'http://192.168.1.3:7001/WebServiceSecurityOWSM-simple_ws-context-root/SimpleServicePort?WSDL'
client = Client(url)
print client

#simple function with no operation on input...
result = client.service.sopHello()
print result
result = client.service.add10(10)
print result

params = client.factory.create('paramBean')
print params

params.intval = 10
params.longval = 20
params.strval = 'string value'
#print "params"
print params

try:
    result = client.service.printParamBean(params)
    print result
except WebFault, e:
    print e

try:
    result = client.service.modifyParamBean(params)
    print result
except WebFault, e:
    print e

print params
```

webservice java class:

```
package simple_ws;

import javax.jws.Oneway;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;


public class SimpleService {
    public SimpleService() {

    }

    public void sopHello(int i) {
        System.out.println("sopHello: hello");
    }


    public int add10(int i) {
        System.out.println("add10:");
        return 10+i;
    }


    public void printParamBean(ParamBean pb) {
        System.out.println(pb);

    }
    public ParamBean modifyParamBean(ParamBean pb) {
        System.out.println(pb);
        pb.setIntval(pb.getIntval()+10);
        pb.setStrval(pb.getStrval()+"blah blah");
        pb.setLongval(pb.getLongval()+200);
        return pb;
    }

}
```

and the bean Class:

```
package simple_ws;

public class ParamBean {
    int intval;
    String strval;
    long longval;

    public void setIntval(int intval) {
        this.intval = intval;
    }

    public int getIntval() {
        return intval;
    }

    public void setStrval(String strval) {
        this.strval = strval;
    }

    public String getStrval() {
        return strval;
    }

    public void setLongval(long longval) {
        this.longval = longval;
    }

    public long getLongval() {
        return longval;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String stri = "\nInt val:" +intval;
        String strstr = "\nstrval val:" +strval;
        String strl = "\nlong val:" +longval;

        return stri+strstr+strl;
    }
}
```

so, as issue is like this:

on call: `client.service.printParamBean(params)` in python client, 
output on server side is:

```
Int val:0
strval val:null
long val:0
```

but on call: `client.service.modifyParamBean(params)`

Client output is:

```
(reply){
   intval = 10
   longval = 200
   strval = "nullblah blah"
 }
```

What am i doing wrong here??

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it the server-side operation `printParamBean` is only printing what you're passing it, but is not returning anything.  Compared to `modifyParamBean` which is both printing and returning value. Could this be your problem?

I surmise that renaming (strictly for the sake of clarity) `printParamBean` to `getParamBean` and having it return what you passed it, might do what you're expecting.